# Coding exercise - grabbing garbage for each player movement python

Tags: python

Imagine a bi-dimensional grid (NxN) where each square has garbage in it, for each movement described by N, S, E, W (for north, south, east and west), the player moves accordingly and grabs the garbage there was in that square.

If the input = 'NESW' the output should be = 4
- 1 for square the player started
- 1 going north, 1 going East, 1 going South and 0 going West because he reaches the initial square where he started which is already "cleaned"

For input = 'NSNSNSNS' output = 2 for the same reason.

I'm having trouble counting the garbage and knowing if the player already went to that place.

```
def total_garbage(positions):
  garbage = 0
  N, S, E, W = 0, 0, 0, 0

  for direction in positions:

    if direction.upper() == 'N':
      N += 1
      garbage += 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'S':
      S += 1
      garbage += 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'E':
      E += 1
      garbage += 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'W':
      W += 1
      garbage += 1

  if N == S and E == W and E != 0 and W != 0:
    return garbage
  elif N == S and E == 0 and W == 0:
    return (garbage - min(N,S))

qp = total_garbage(['N','E','S','W'])
print(qp)
```

This is what I have so far, it was just to start and try some stuff, but haven't been very successful :/

Comment: I would suggest creating an array the size of your grid, ideally using `numpy`. The array values can be initialized to 0, and if the player has went to that square you can change it to 1. Is your grid finite or infinite? This way you can also play arıund with it, put multiple pieces of garbage on a single tile etc.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ahmet - for this numpy is a complete overkill - since you only need to track where you have bee just use a set.

Comment: You need a data structure to hold the locations that have already been visited. There are a few ways to do this. If you know the size of the grid, then you can make a boolean array, like Ahmet noted. I would recommend storing the locations in a `Set`. You'll need to compute the `x, y` coordinates of the location instead of your N E S W method because a location has a unique `x, y` representation. When you visit a new location, create a `tuple` with the (x, y) coordinates. If that tuple is in your `visited` set, then you do not need to increment the garbage count.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I will try some of the suggestions and see what I got :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array as Ahmet proposed in the comments, but if you do not want to you could do this like this:

```py
x, y = 0, 0 # this will be our position 
visited_idx = set() # indexes where we have already gathered garbage
for direction in positions:
    if direction.upper() == 'N':
      y += 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'S':
      y -= 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'E':
      x += 1
    elif direction.upper() == 'W':
      x -= 1

    current_idx = (x,y)
    # You wrote that there is no garbage in the first cell hence the second codition
    if current_idx not in visited_idx and current_idx != (0,0):
        visited_idx.add(current_idx)

units_of_garbage_gathered = len(visited_idx)
```

Comment: using a set would be better than a list to keep track of where has been visited.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I will try some of the suggestions and see what I got :)

Comment: I feel bad for how easy it was, because I also had tried with x, y but wasn't checking and adding like this :/ still a bit unfamiliar with all the data types in python. Thank you! :) this helped a lot!

Comment: Are you aware why set is better here than list?

Comment: Hmm maybe not, I would say because it's easier to check if (x,y) is in the set and doesn't allow duplicates. while in lists I would need to iterate (do a for loop) to check if (x,y) is already in the list. But i'm not quite sure to be honest.

Comment: @havord - that is exactly the reason; in your application you want checking to be fast, and you don't care about duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

since your grid is two dimensional, model it as a 2D grid - so choose a starting location (say (0,0)) and each direction alters that location - so from (0,0):

- N becomes (0,-1)
- S becomes (0,1)
- E becomes (1,0)
- W becomes (-1,0)

and so on

You store the locations you have visited in a python set - and before you go to a new location, you check if that location isn't already in a set. That is if you want only one piece of garbage per location - if you want eventually to have mutliple pieces, you can model the grid as a dictionary; but as a set -

```
def total_garbage(positions):

    # Create a dictionary translating direction to co-ordinate changes
    deltas = {'N':(0,-1),'S':{0,1),'E':(1,0),'W':(-1,0)}

    cleaned_locations = set()
    start_location = (0,0)
    garbage = 0

    for direction in positions:
        dx, dy = deltas[direction]
        x,y = start_location
        nx, xy = x + dx, y+dx

       # Count this site so long as it isn't already cleaned.
       if (nx, ny) not in cleaned:
          garbage += 1
          cleaned.add((nx,ny))
      else:
          return garbage

qp = total_garbage(['N','E','S','W'])
print(qp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much fo the help! I will try and see what I got :) Thank you!

Comment: feel free to upvote or accept (use the tick) the answer

Comment: I accepted other (just because it was the one I used) and I can't upvote :/ tells me I need more reputation to do so, I'm sorry! But thank you!

Comment: ah well - ...they are the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

First, when I run this code, I get 4 as I believe you are looking for. If you want to know if garbage was already collected in your square, I think you might need to track that in parallel to your movements and collections.. there are a few ways you could do this, I would suggest a list of lists for your grid, if you wanted a 3x3 grid, create something like :

```
grid = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

you can now have something to keep track of where garbage has been picked and if there is any to be picked.

So now, your next step would be to figure out a starting point like

```
grid[0][0]
```

then if you move up one, you would be in

```
grid[1][0]
```

if you visit that spot, in your function, do something like:

```
newPos = grid[1][0]
if (newPos != 1) {
     // do your collecting and change grid[1][0] form 0 to 1
} else {
     // don't collect, track your movement or whatever else you want.
}
```

I hope that was helpful! Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much fo the help! I will try and see what I got :) Thank you!